# Get All Months & Years between Date Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Example user input ‘startdate’ = July 2017, ‘enddate’ = March 2019. I’ve been able to input it into filters by using `>startdate` & `<enddate` but need the numbers to populate this way.

How do I list all months and years between the 2 on a worksheet?

```
July 2017
August 2017
September 2017
...
March 2019
```

Comment: Are you using this with a filter? Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: @BigBen apologies, have attempted to structure my question better. I've been able to obtain the data I want using the filters. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get all the dates in that date range to populate on a worksheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to loop through each month between the 2 dates:

```
Dim tempDate As Date: tempDate = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
Dim endDate As Date: endDate = Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value

Dim i As Integer: i = 3

Do While tempDate < endDate
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = MonthName(DatePart("m", tempDate)) & " " & DatePart("yyyy", tempDate)
    tempDate = DateAdd("m", 1, tempDate)    
    i = i + 1
Loop
```